# Subdivision makes one part of my knife thicker than the other

Tags: modeling

https://gyazo.com/0378ac77fdd3d4756cea85b0990cb684
https://gyazo.com/2646c6698b74b056077a73a3347fec11
Any help?
When I try to subdivide this edge it seems to make the width uneven with the rest of the models width.

Comment: Hi, welcome! Please add images here using the question editor image tool, so they get embedded in your post, permanently. I will help others to help you, thank!

Answer (score 0):

Simple. You just have to select "Simple"  : )
[image]